# Can I use ROS to control Parrot's Bebop

Tags: ros, bebop-autonomy, ardrone, parrot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been working with ArDrone Autonomy package to control Parrot's ardrone 1.0 and 2.0.

Now I want to work with the new drone and I was wondering how to do it. Can I use ardrone autonomy? Should I change any configuration? Is there any specific package to use Bebop?

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206099/can-i-use-ros-to-control-parrot%27s-bebop/) by [alexrodriv](https://answers.ros.org/users/22004/alexrodriv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2015-03-27

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nanaky](https://answers.ros.org/users/5617/nanaky/) on 2015-04-01**:
I have the same question. Waiting for an answer!!!

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2015-05-01**:
I also would like to know how to do that ! I only know this repository : https://github.com/ARDroneSDK3
Haven't tried it yet, but it should be possible to link it to ROS.

**Comment by [Anurag VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/29692/anurag-vv/) on 2017-04-21**:
I am very eager to know the answer to this question. Primarily because I do not exactly know how the controller for ardrone or hector_quadrotor are implemented. It is all very confusing. I keep going in circles. There is no one pipeline layout of how the urdf, dynamics, control are all coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Update 2:** It's possible now: https://github.com/AutonomyLab/bebop_autonomy

Bebop drone uses a different protocol than Ardrone, therefor it can not be interfaced through [ArdroneLIB SDK](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardronelib). That's the reason why `ardrone_autonomy` is incompatible with Bebop drone. There is currently no ROS driver to control Bebop. As @Cyril_J said, Parrot has released [ARDoneSDK3](https://github.com/ARDroneSDK3) for Bebop drone. I'll provide my insights about this SDK as a comment.

**Update 1:** Paparazzi project [supports Bebop](https://wiki.paparazziuav.org/wiki/Bebop). I have not yet tried this solution, but it might be possible to bridge `ivy` (Paparazzi's comm protocol) to ROS either directly or through [mavlink <-> ivy](https://github.com/mavlink/mavlink-ivy-interface) bridge. ([More info](https://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/%7Eoberthol/html/Report_Robotics_ARDrone.html))

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2015-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2015-05-14**:
I am the maintainer/developer of `ardrone_autonomy`. I got access to Bebop drone a couple of weeks ago and tested and hacked it for a couple of days. The drone itself is a major improvement over Ardrone 2.0. However there is no developer guide for the SDK. (cont)

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2015-05-14**:
The underlying protocol, the network layer configuration and the logic behind the framework is not clear. The SDK comes with a C example that shows how to control the drone with keyboard and read the video stream. In principal one can build a ROS driver around this example. (cont)

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2015-05-14**:
I decided not to do that for now for couple of reasons 1) Extra effort is needed to understand how the SDK work.  It means longer development time which I could not commit to 2) Since the protocol is not documented, it is not clear if the streaming video quality can be improved (cont)

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2015-05-14**:
Currently the streaming video quality is poor with lag and jitter. With this quality, it is not a useful platform for vision processing tasks, which I am personally interested in. If anyone is interested to discuss the options and solutions, please feel free to contact me.